Running playwright in docker. Error:BrowserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1134/chrome-linux/chrome
I created a Dockerfile with this content
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Install requirements
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget tar openjdk-17-jre
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gcc libsnmp-dev iputils-ping -y  \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && apt-get -y install curl \
    && apt-get clean


# Install allure
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.30.0/allure-2.30.0.tgz && \
    tar -zxvf allure-2.30.0.tgz -C /opt/ && \
    ln -s /opt/allure-2.30.0/bin/allure /usr/bin/allure && \
    rm allure-2.30.0.tgz

# Create workdir
WORKDIR /usr/workspace

# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/workspace

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Install playwright
RUN playwright install --with-deps chromium

and I use docker-compose to run it.
version: "3.7"

services:
  tests:
    image: tests:v1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/workspace
    command: /bin/sh -c 'python3 -m pytest -v -m $MARKS --alluredir=./allure-results --node_id="$NODE_ID"'
    working_dir: /usr/workspace
    user: "997:997"

everything runs locally without problems, but when it runs in CI on gitlab-runner, an error occurs
playwright._impl._errors.Error: BrowserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1134/chrome-linux/chrome

chromium is installed in the installation logs
Chromium 129.0.6668.29 (playwright build v1134) downloaded to /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1134

I tried to install chromium in different ways, the result is the same, everything is fine locally, but when in gitlab-runner, there is always an error. Gitlab-runner itself is just a shell
RUN playwright install chromium
RUN playwright install --with-deps chromium
RUN playwright install-deps chromium


Check out this medium post. It might be helpful.
If the medium post doesn't work. The crude hack is to specify the execuatble_path in your browser launch in your code. Make it match the location installed when RUN playwright install --with-deps was executed.
For example

browsers_path = "/root/.cache/ms-playwright"
chromium_version = "chromium-1134"  # Replace this dynamically if needed
executable_path = f"{browsers_path}/{chromium_version}/chrome-linux/chrome"

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(
        executable_path=executable_path,  # Path to installed Chromium
        headless=True
    )
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()

   

    browser.close()

